# Ruby binding instance_eval access to local vars?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, eval

Working on some functionality where I need to be able to define methods and local vars from strings via a `binding`

I think the code speaks best for itself, so here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
mybind = binding

mybind.eval("a = 5")
mybind.eval("a") #=> 5

a #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a'...
# Calling it in global/main scope doesn't find anything, but it's found in the `mybind` scope

mybind.eval("def thing; 3; end")
mybind.eval("thing") #=> 3

thing #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `thing'...
# Calling it in global/main scope doesn't find anything, but it's found in the `mybind` scope
```

Essentially, I don't want any methods/vars defined to go to the global scope, but I want them to be callable within a second call to the same binding/eval. These will come through as strings, so callable blocks is out of the question as well.

I've tried `instance_eval`, `class_eval`, `eval`, and `instance_exec`

`instance_eval` is ALMOST perfect, except for some reason any local vars defined cannot be accessed within the next `instance_eval` called.

I'm a bit new to using `binding`, so if there is something obvious I'm missing, please let me know. Otherwise if there is anybody that has any idea on how to accomplish this, even with a different flow I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

I'm on Ruby 2.7.2, but can upgrade if that will provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`binding`, by its design, gets the *current* binding whenever it's called. If you call it in the global scope, you'll get the global binding. What it sounds like you want is a binding that's not accessible to the user. We can create one of those easily, simply by calling `binding` inside of an otherwise empty function.

```
def new_binding
  binding
end
```

Now, every time I call `new_binding`, I get a fresh scope that inherits lexically from Ruby's standard global scope but that nobody else can access without that object.

```
irb(main):012:0> new_binding == new_binding
=> false
irb(main):013:0> my_binding = new_binding
=> #<Binding:0x00005562fd103a00>
irb(main):014:0> my_binding.eval("a = 1")
=> 1
irb(main):015:0> my_binding.eval("a")
=> 1
```

--

*Edit after your comment*

We can get a little closer to what you're looking for by wrapping `new_binding` in a trivial eigenclass.

```
def new_binding
  class <<Object.new
    return binding
  end
end
```

Now you can define methods, but you have to do so with an explicit `self`.

```
new_binding.eval("def self.thing; 3; end")
new_binding.eval("thing")
```

It's very possible there's some trickery that can be done with [`method_added`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-method_added) to get around the explicit receiver, but for whatever reason it seems like `method_added` doesn't want to work on eigenclasses. I might end up opening a new SO question about that myself to be honest, as the behavior is quite odd.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will define methods at a global level: `my_binding.eval("def d; 5; end")` `d #=> 5`
I may just accept this as is since it doesn't seem doable to work around this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the bit about methods. I'll edit the answer if I think of a workaround. There may be some magic we can do.

Comment: Yeah- the methods part is what I’m struggling with. I understand why the methods are being defined globally, just wish there was a way I could somehow define them in a contextual scope. For now I’ll leave as is, as I’ve spent too much time trying to fix it. Thanks for the help!